# Why can't I launch eclipse from a terminal or run it via gmrun?

Tags: gnome-terminal, gmrun

I can't launch eclipse from either terminal or gmrun but I can do so using Applications -> Programming -> Eclipse.

Here are the screenshots:

1) Using `Gmrun`: I can see that `gmrun` is recognizing the `eclipse` command but when I enter it, nothing happens.

[image]

2) Using Terminal: when I type `eclipse`, I get the following message:

[image: terminal]

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Ubuntu has its own directories from which it will check for applications (like `/usr/bin`). So If you just downloaded eclipse to `/opt` then of course it won't be recognized. If you want it to be recognized, you have two options, either install from Ubuntu standard repos (with disadvantage missing latest version) or install your eclipse on those directories / symlink it (both unrecommended).

BTW why not `cd /opt/eclipse` and just run `./eclipse`?

Comment: I want to able to run eclipse from run dialog box..You think thats not possible with current setup?

Comment: You have to add symlink that will pretend as if eclispe runs from "system" directories. For example you can create symlink of eclipse executable in /usr/local/eclipse. For more on symlinks check
http://www.unixtutorial.org/2008/02/unix-symlink-example/

Comment: @Stefano These are not the only two options. As [lol xD](http://askubuntu.com/users/70980/lol-xd)'s [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/151658/22949) details, you can add the directory that contains the `eclipse` binary to the `PATH` environment variable. This method is quite standard, quick, and elegant.

Comment: You are right! I think finding a PPA with latest eclipse version might be better option. I remember one time I saw it somewhere!

Answer (score 2):

Do the following steps to fix it. Assume you extracted `eclipse` in `/opt/eclipse`. Your `eclipse` executable's path is `/opt/eclipse/eclipse`

**Fix permission**

```
sudo chmod -R a+x /opt/eclipse
```

**Make a link of `eclipse` (executable)**

```
sudo ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin/eclipse
```

**Again fix the permission**

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/eclipse
```

**Check in terminal to ensure that system detects eclipse**
which eclipse

```
output: /usr/local/bin/eclipse
```

Now you can run eclipse by typing eclipse in `terminal` or search in `gmrun` (ATL+F2)

Comment: This thread is little bit older. but answer it for future reference.

Comment: It says; `chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink [path]`

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe you could try to change your `$PATH` environment variable in the `.profile` file in your home directory? Like adding a line `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/eclipse` to the file (at or near the end of the file).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

open `~/.bashrc` with your favourite editor and add the following lines to the end of the file:

```
if [ -d "/opt/eclipse" ] ; then
    PATH="/opt/eclipse:$PATH"
fi
```

Close and open the terminal.

This is what I did in Unity and it worked for me. I am not quite sure if it will work on the Gnome environment.