# Why can't I launch eclipse from a terminal ? change $PATH environment variable

Tags: command-line, eclipse, environment-variables

I want to run eclipse via terminal.

Eclipse is in this directory `~/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/`.

When I write in terminal `cd ~/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/` and then `./eclipse` it works.

But how can I set the `PATH` in the `.profile` file to only type in eclipse and it runs the program?

I tried it like explained in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/a/151658/22949):

I set `export PATH=$PATH:~/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/` at the end of the `.profile` file and saved it.

Now when I type `eclipse` in the terminal it says

```
command 'eclipse' not found.
```

Comment: You probably just need to log out and back in? BTW, rather than using I suggest quoting, like `PATH="$PATH:$HOME/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse"` and you don't need to `export` because PATH is always an environment variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu!

`.profile` is sourced only for "login" shells.

Usually when starting a new terminal from the GUI the shell is a "non-login" shell.

Try putting your `$PATH` into `.bashrc` which is sourced for every new terminal.